# SQL Query for Gridview with Count and Group by

Tags: sql, asp.net

In my aspx+VB+sql web i have a gridview to display the summary of purchase

if I use this query then i get Vendor wise summary correctly

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), Date,105) as Date, Vendor, SUM(Quantity) As Quantity, SUM(Rate) As Rate 
FROM Procurement 
GROUP BY Date,Vendor
```

But I wanted the total amount by multiplying Quantity and Rate and get amount. I used this query. But in this i am not getting the vendor wise summary which was I looking ofr.

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), Date,105) as Date, Vendor, SUM(qty) As Quantity, SUM(Rate) As Rate, Qty * Rate as Amount 
FROM Procurement 
GROUP BY Date,Vendor,Qty,Rate
```

I want the output like this

```
Date  Vendor  Quantity  Rate  Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your not taking the aggregate sum of qty and sum of rate to get the amount. You also need to group by those columns that are not in the aggregate as right now it is only selecting each individual row.

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), Date,105) as Date, Vendor, 
SUM(qty) As Quantity, SUM(Rate) As Rate, SUM(Qty) * SUM(Rate) as Amount 
FROM Procurement 
GROUP BY Date, Vendor
```

Comment: Doesn't the GROUP BY need to use `Convert(varchar(10), Date,105)` as opposed to `Date` ?

Comment: Yes, Need to take the aggregate sum of  Rate and qty

Comment: I was not able to proceed as this query is calculating the total sum of rate and total sum of qty and showing the amount 

Actually I was looking for multiplying rate and Qty of each product and then get the consolidated summary of a vendor

Comment: I had created a schema here.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fad34/2

Comment: each product is having different rates and qty. i want the summary of one vendor how much money i had spent on one vendor to buy product

Comment: for example Foodies Corner.  I had purchased 2 products from this vendor having 11kg and rate is Rs 42 and 2nd product  qty is 20 and Rs 54 logically the summary should show amount  as Rs 1542     (11 x 42 = 462  and  20 x 54 = 1080)  but in my query its is calculating 11+20 = 31 and multiplying with 42+54= 96  and result is 2976 instead of 1542

Comment: If i edit the query as under. then calculation sis correct but i will not get the summary of a vendor

Comment: SELECT Vendor,
SUM(qty) As Quantity, SUM(Rate) As Rate, SUM(Qty) * SUM(Rate) as Amount 
FROM Procurement 
GROUP BY Qty,Rate,Vendor